# Unknown monitor problem

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, monitor

My display settings detects another display besides my Built In Monitor on an Asus Aspire 5755G. So I allways have my Built in Display and a second Uknown Monitor. I can deactivate this display (unknowns) from the on/off button but this is frustrating after doing it every time I log in or out. I red some forums and some people say that the problem goes away after installing the Nvidia Drivers. The problem is that I did and after install the screen allways went black leaving me only with the cursor and the ctrl+alt+f1 console for commend so I managed uninstalling it to get my dektop back. So if annyone could help out with this problem that would be great. I just updated to 13.10. Didn't have this problem on 13.04. THX

Answer (score 0):

It dissapered on my Lenovo G780 after installing bumblebee.

If you have a optimus Asus this would probably be a way to go:

[Installation is a bit longer down for Bumblebee](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/8-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html)

Comment: I have a Geforce 540M and accordin to Nvidia it does hqave Optimus Technology. I will try your suggestion and come back if it worsk out. Thanks!